# Add way to save last few custom tag sorts in new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, new-nav

I like the "custom tags" filter.  It's really nifty, particularly as I can have a few tags that I browse simultaneously in it.

BUT, unless I alter my favorites (which I don't want to do), I can't "save" a custom tags filter.  So next time I visit SO, it's gone - or even if I change to a different view and switch back.

Maybe I want to look at SAS-related questions, but not miss ones in minor tags only, so I see [sas](/questions/tagged/sas) [sas-macro](/questions/tagged/sas-macro) [sas-ods](/questions/tagged/sas-ods) [sas-iml](/questions/tagged/sas-iml).  Then I want to view Excel questions, so I go to [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba).  Now I can't get back to the earlier custom filter.

Can we have a "history" of the last few you've used - preferably "ever" in any session, but if that's too hard, at least the last few you've used in the current session?  Either something over near your favorite tags, or another option in the drop down.

Comment: Note that I realize you could bookmark the search - but it seems more helpful to do it in the navigation itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not going to be done in the next iteration, but enabling saved sets is certainly one of the reasons why we are doing this kind of navigation.

For the moment you can simply save browser bookmarks with the custom tags you like.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!