# Easy way to get back to last view from question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

This isn't particularly different from the original view, but since we're making all these changes...

My normal workflow is [click on favorite tag] -> [click on question] -> [click on tag in question to go back], or sometimes from the question [click on SO top] -> [click on tag from favorites] if it's a long question (so the tags are offscreen).

This isn't exactly a huge amount of work, but now that we have custom filters, maybe I want to use them.  I already asked about [saving custom filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256831/add-way-to-save-last-few-custom-tag-sorts-in-new-navigation), and of course that will help - but it's still several clicks now to get back to the view.  We can use "back" on browser to navigate back to that view, but sometimes I might be three or four questions deep (if a question's linked whatnot took me down a few).

Can we add a button or option somewhere on the view question page that returns us to the last view we were on?  Or, alternately, clicking on StackOverflow logo up at top takes us back to that last view (this would seem optimal to me, but I realize other people may use it differently).

Comment: I'll often open a question in a new tab and then just close the tab after I'm finished browsing the question/chain.

Comment: I do the same as the above comment. If you ctrl+click the question (on Chrome at least) it will open it in a new tab. Then the original view remains open. I also make copious use of Chrome's "close all tabs to the right" feature when I finish. Personally, I support keeping site navigation conveniences at a minimum and letting the user rely on browser UI features instead, but that might just be me.

Comment: Problem with that is I have a lot of tabs already for other things - I'd rather not have to open a new tab for each SO question I navigate to (and remembering to close them is not necessarily consistent).  I like having one window for SO, most of the time.  (I do sometimes open in new windows for specific reasons, but not just for browsing questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.